# Como executar um arquivo .sql contendo uma procedure (oracle) em Java

Tags: java, jdbc, procedure

tenho esse script dentro de um arquivo de nome xxx.sql

como faço para criar a procedure através de uma chamada dentro do código java?

```
DECLARE

   PROCEDURE P_GERA_LOG(P_TEXTO IN VARCHAR2)
   IS
   BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS')||' - '||P_TEXTO);
   END P_GERA_LOG;  
  
   PROCEDURE SLEEP(P_SEGUNDOS IN INT) IS
      V_NOW DATE := SYSDATE;
   BEGIN
      LOOP
         EXIT WHEN SYSDATE >= V_NOW + (P_SEGUNDOS * (1/86400));
      END LOOP;   
   END SLEEP;
END;
/
DISCONNECT;
EXIT;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Em primeiro lugar, a procedure está gravada no banco?
Porque normalmente uma procedure é um procedimento que fica vamos dizer "armazenado no banco" e você chama para que ele seja executado.
Ou você quer criar a procedure através de uma chamada em java? Isso não compreendi 100%.

Vamos supor que a procedure esteja em banco. Se estiver, vou passar aqui um modelo de execução de chamada.

```
CallableStatement cs;
String retorno;
try {
    // Prepara a chamada
    cs = connection.prepareCall("{call P_GERA_LOG(?)}");

    // Registra um parametro
    cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);

    // passa o parametro
    cs.setString(1, "a string");  

    // executa a procedure
    cs.execute();

    // obtem o retorno
   retorno = cs.getString(1);
} catch (SQLException e) {
}
```

Após seu comentário de que você deseja criar uma procedure através de uma chamada em Java, vou tentar replicar aqui um código.

```
public void criarProcedure(Connection con) throws SQLException {

    Statement stmtCriarProcedure = null;

    // ...

    String queryCriaProcedure =
        "CREATE PROCEDURE NOME_PROCEDURE() " +
        "conteudo da procedure...";

    // ...

    try {
        System.out.println("Chamando CREATE PROCEDURE");
        stmtCriarProcedure = con.createStatement();
        stmtCriarProcedure.execute(queryCriaProcedure)
        // ...

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // ... trata a exception da maneira que achar melhor
    } finally {
        if (stmtCriarProcedure != null) {
            stmtCriarProcedure.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quero criar a procedure através de uma chamada.

Comment: Oi Luis Marcelo! Eu realizei a adição de um código. Eu não consigo testar em minha máquina porque não tenho uma base oracle especificamente instalada. Tenho apenas outros bancos. No caso, adicionei um código que usa JDBC básico, usando statement para execução.

Comment: Implementei, e o retorno foi: Error: ORA-01031: privilégios insuficientes. 
Realmente as permissões do user que conecta na base não possui tais privilégios.

Answer (score 0):

A solução foi implementar utilizando ScriptRunner:

```
ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(conexão com BD);
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("aqui o arquivo xxx.sql"));
sr.setSendFullScript(true);
sr.setAutoCommit(true);
sr.setStopOnError(true);
sr.runScript(reader);
sr.closeConnection();
```